# find font from the scanned image

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image]

I am working for my client creating his stationary printing, he wish to have the same font used in this image. I was tired searching the font, so I seek your expertise to find the font in the attached image.

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 2):

Probably it can match [Eurostile](http://www.myfonts.com/search/Eurostile/fonts/) font

[image]